# Calculating integral bounds for desired power level?

Tags: integration

## Context

I am building an oven temperature controller and want to perform standard AC power control by applying only part of each half-cycle.

I already have the necessary circuitry to sense each zero-crossing and trigger a component known as a [TRIAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIAC) which starts off in a non-conductive state but, once triggered, will conduct until the current drops back to zero at the next zero-crossing. [This GIF](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3b/Triac_funktion.gif) illustrates the process perfectly.

## The Challenge

At each zero-crossing the micro-controller must trigger the TRIAC after a calculated interval in order to apply the power commanded by the PID control.

"Ok easy", I thought to myself, and when the time came to write the power controlling section of the firmware I grabbed a piece of paper and jumped right in.

I decided I would write out an equation for the applied relative power by dividing the integral of the section after an interval $T$ by the integral of the whole half-cycle, this way, regardless of the actual power value, PID would be able to control the power linearly from 0% to 100% and be fully abstracted away from any mains or oven specifics.

#### So far:

Will consider $ V_{peak}=1V $
Will refer to the mains frequency as $ f $
Will refer to the time delay from each zero-crossing to TRIAC activation as $T$
Will refer to the relative power as $ P_r $

Mains: $ V(t) = V_{peak}*sin(tf2\pi) $
100% power of one half-cycle: $ \int _0 ^\frac{1}{2f} V(t)^2 dt = \frac {1}{4f} $
Power of one half-cycle given the delay $T$:
$ \int _T ^\frac{1}{2f} V(t)^2 dt = \frac {π(2-4fT) + sin(4fπT)} {8fπ} $

Finally, relative power given T:
$$
P_r(T) =
\frac {\int _T ^\frac{1}{2f} V(t)^2 dt} {\int _0 ^\frac{1}{2f} V(t)^2 dt} =
\frac {\frac {π(2-4fT) + sin(4fπT)} {8fπ}} {\frac {1}{4f}} =
\frac {π(2-4fT) + sin(Tf4π)} {2π}
$$

TLDR

I'm stuck trying to find the inverse function of $P_r(T)$ so that I can calculate the required time delay T with respect to a target relative power.
I just can't seem to manage, is there a better way of doing this? Am I not seeing something?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You seek to solve a transcendental equation for $T$. Such equations typically have no analytic solution. You could pre-compute a table of $\{P(u),u\}$ values where $u=fT$ then lookup $u$ for a given $P$

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I also thought about a lookup table but this would be the ideal solution. I will use one since the time values scale nicely with frequency so we don't need to compute it at boot.